# Query Geonames data from GraphDB

Tags: sparql, graphdb, geonames

Is it possible to query Geonames data from GraphDB? For instance, I am trying to query the triplets of http://sws.geonames.org/2993365/about.rdf from the SPARQL interface of GraphDB but the following requests (which is working on http://sparql.org/sparql.html) does not retrieve any results:

```
select * from <http://sws.geonames.org/2993365/about.rdf> where {?s ?p ?o}
```

Thank you,

Comment: You could query only data exposed through a remote sparql endpoints using `SERVICE` ...

Comment: The other option is create a local repository, load the remote data using `LOAD <data-url>` into it and query it locally ...

Comment: Indeed, this query retrieves results using GeoSPARQL endpoint: `SELECT * WHERE { SERVICE <http://www.lotico.com:3030/lotico/sparql> { SELECT * WHERE { <http://sws.geonames.org/2993365/> ?p ?o. } } }
LIMIT 100`. Thank you,